# PhpMailer Authentication Error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to configure email by using phpmailer and smtp but Authentication error appears.
Code below

```
include_once("phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$tarih = date("d.m.Y - H:i:s");

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "mail.golcukdh.gov.tr";

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "username";

$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->From     = "email";

$mail->AddAddress("email");

$mail->Subject = "subject";

$mail->Body = "Body Part";

$mail->Send()

?>
```

I tried to configure this by using asp.net with these authentication information and it was successfull. But I want to use php, what is wrong ?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message?

Comment: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Comment: please add $mail->SMTPDebug = true; and post output again.